# How to get Altitude from Latitude and Longitude or Google Map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am implement **Google Map** in Android , and I got the `Latitude` and the `Longitude` via `onMapClick` like the following code.

```
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    Log.d(TAG,"latLng.latitude = " + latLng.latitude);
    Log.d(TAG,"latLng.longitude = " + latLng.longitude);
}
```

But it did not have Altitude data.

**Q1:
How to get the Altitude of position which I click on the Google Map?**

or

**Q2:
How to get the Altitude via known Latitude and Longitude ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an HTTP call to the Google Maps Elevation API, documented at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro.  I don't believe that there is native Android client library for this API.  You can make a request including latitude/longitude and receive elevation information in the response.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method [Location.getAltitude()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAltitude)

Comment: Is this accurate?